# Using pointers to parameterize functions

Tags: pointers, fortran, closures

I have a function (y = f(x,a) = x^a) that takes two input arguments. I want to reduce f(x,a) to f(x) such that f has a built into it.

Currently I'm able to create a pointer to a function using the provided module and program example below. What I want to do instead is somehow initialize the pointer with a parameter so that instead of calling a function with 2 parameters I can use just one.

I need to parameterize function calls so for later use in other routines (e.g. integration, differentiation, etc)

Is this possible using some combination of abstract interfaces, functions, subroutines, and pointers?

```
module example
  implicit none

  abstract interface
    pure function fun1(x) result(y)
      real, intent(in):: x
      real:: y
    end function fun1

    pure function fun2(x, a) result(y)
      real, intent(in):: x, a
      real:: y
    end function fun2
  end interface

contains

  pure function myfun(xx, aa) result(yy)
    real, intent(in):: xx, aa
    real:: yy
    yy = xx**aa
    return
  end function myfun

end module example


program test_ptr
  use example, only: fun1, fun2, myfun
  implicit none

  real:: x, a, y
  procedure(fun2), pointer :: ptr => null()

  x = 2.0
  a = 1.5

  ptr => myfun
  y = ptr(x, a)

  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

end program test_ptr
```

Comment: Have you tried enclosing your functions and/or subroutines inside a derived data type as generic type-bound procedures.

Comment: I don't know what generic type-bound procedures are, how can they be used to solve my problem?

Comment: One other thing you may be able to consider is parameterizing a module procedure with a module variable.  There is a variety of related questions, but no single good one to point you towards.  "closure" and "anonymous" may be good search terms to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I thought I figured it out, but the pointer is destroyed after the first call to the function. Calling a pointer more than once results in a Seg Fault.

I was playing around a bit with my source before my question to see if I could get it myself, and I think I figured it out. I came up with two ways of doing what I needed, the first using a function with an internal function, and the second with a subroutine, also with an internal function.

Both of them rely on the fact that the internal function has access to the 'parent' function/subroutine's variables

I'm still wondering if it's possible to do this with an external function, or if the only way is to use internal functions.

If anyone has some input, I would love to hear about it.

EDIT: Apparently you can also call external functions from the internal function, thereby just creating a wrapper around an already known function.

```
module example
  implicit none

  abstract interface
    pure function fun1(x) result(y)
      real, intent(in):: x
      real:: y
    end function fun1

    pure function fun2(x, a) result(y)
      real, intent(in):: x, a
      real:: y
    end function fun2
  end interface

contains

  pure function myfun(xx, aa) result(yy)
    real, intent(in):: xx, aa
    real:: yy
    yy = xx**aa
    return
  end function myfun

  pure function set_ptr(aa) result(ptr)
    real, intent(in):: aa
    procedure(fun1), pointer :: ptr
    ptr => localfun
    return
  contains
    pure function localfun(xx) result(yy)
      real, intent(in):: xx
      real:: yy
      yy = xx**aa
    end function localfun
  end function set_ptr

  pure subroutine mysub(aa, ptr)
    real, intent(in):: aa
    procedure(fun1), intent(out), pointer :: ptr
    ptr => localfun
    return
  contains
    pure function localfun(xx) result(yy)
      real, intent(in):: xx
      real:: yy
      yy = xx**aa
    end function localfun
  end subroutine mysub

  pure function set_ptr2(aa) result(ptr)
    real, intent(in):: aa
    procedure(fun1), pointer :: ptr
    ptr => myfun_wrapper
    return
  contains
    pure function myfun_wrapper(xx) result(yy)
      real, intent(in):: xx
      real:: yy
      yy = myfun(xx, aa)
    end function myfun_wrapper
  end function set_ptr2

end module example



program test_ptr
  use example, only: fun1, fun2, myfun, mysub, set_ptr, set_ptr2
  implicit none

  real:: x, a, y
  procedure(fun2), pointer :: ptr1 => null()
  procedure(fun1), pointer :: ptr2 => null()
  procedure(fun1), pointer :: ptr3 => null()
  procedure(fun1), pointer :: ptr4 => null()

  x = 2.0
  a = 1.5

  ptr1 => myfun
  y = ptr1(x, a)
  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

  ptr2 = set_ptr(a)
  y = ptr2(x)
  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

  call mysub(a, ptr3)
  y = ptr3(x)
  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

  ptr4 = set_ptr2(a)
  y = ptr4(x)
  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

*** The next line will result in an error ***
  y = ptr4(x)
  write(*,*) x, '^', a, ' = ', y

end program test_ptr
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is not valid.  Once the host subprogram has completed execution the pointer to an internal procedure becomes undefined.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I was able to get the above code to run using gfortran 4.8.5

Comment: Procedure `set_ptr2` will make a trampoline (thunk) on its stack telling ho to access the internal procedure `myfun_wrapper` which is inside.  It will make it on its stack. Once `set_ptr2` finishes, it is deleted.

Comment: The compiler can probably avoid the trampoline for very simple functions, but the standard still says this practice is invalid.

Comment: You're right, calling the pointer again results in a `Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.` Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do? Is there a compelling need to use pointers at all?